# How to create live Ubuntu CD and connect using android USB tethering.

Tags: live-usb, tethering

I can boot my old notebook only from usb or cd drive. And I want to connect the internet via my android phone using usb tethering. Windows connects automatically if the phone is connected to the computer via usb cable and I turn the usb tethering on.

I cannot make this auto-connecting part working in slax so I hope that ubuntu would do this for me.

**How do I make a live Ubuntu USB stick?**

Or I have to do this exercise help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick I have only Windows7 available right now.

Furthermore, I would like to know the steps to have my live session connect to the Internet using USB tethering on my android device.

Comment: Uhm.. ok so what do you actually want to do? do you want to create a Live USB or do you want to connect the phone while tethered?.

Comment: Both :-) I guess I need to create a live usb to be able get connected to the internet while tethering. If my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your LiveUSB needs:

Get Unetbootin and an ISO of Ubuntu 11.10

Connect your USB device, Open up Unetbootin, select the ISO image, and then accept, it will then create your Live USB.

For the tethered internet connection, I didn't need to install anything Ubuntu picked up the connection immediately, I have a Galaxy S II.

Comment: Did you use usb or wi-fi tethering?

Comment: I connected the phone to a Wifi router and then connected the phone's USB cable to the PC.

Answer (score 1):

1) Go to the Ubuntu Download page http://www.ubuntu.com/download

2) Select "Try it from a CD or USB stick and then select USB to see the detailed instructions.

3) Once the live session is up and running, connect the android device and select "USB tethering", this will show additional "Wired connection" in Ubuntu and you will be able to connect to the Internet using it.

As Ubuntu comes with android drivers (tested with my HTC Evo and Ubuntu 11.10 32bit). The connection should be up and running in seconds.

Comment: I didn't install anything on my Windows7, it just works....

Comment: That's probably because Win7 installed the drivers the first time you connected. You may need to install the drivers and see the phone-specific instructions for your USB tether plan.

Comment: Hm, how can install the drivers? And actually what drivers?

Comment: I just tested with my android, Ubuntu already has the drivers and I was almost instantly connected. So it should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation;

1-) Download Ubuntu 14.04 and follow the USB installation guide on Ubuntu's web
2-) If your phone has a good ROM, you don't need an apk to run tether, just plug your phone in USB depuration mode and Ubuntu will recognize it as a cable connection. But if you need and apk I suggest Easytether, although is a paid solution, it works. Note: if you download Easytether Lite you won't be able to access to any https.//, you have to purchase (if you want) Easytether Pro.

PdaNet doesn't have a Linux Client side app, ClockWork mode has a Linux app but it's harder to install, there are also others apks like Klink that I haven't tried.

But comparing to my experience in Windows with PdaNet, I must say that tethering experience in Ubuntu is great because it is not hard to set and it's more automatic (Once you plug your phone tether stars).

Answer (score -1):

I am using Samsung Galaxy Y S5360 and USB tethering and Wifi tethering works immediately without the need for any configuration in my Ubuntu 11.04.